# How to stretch a table to another tables height?

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tables that look like this with my current code (had to draw over them because I have sensitive information in them):

[image]

Now as you can see, the table on the right is much smaller than the table on the left, due to the fact that it has less data. I'm using two different data sets for each table so I'm pretty sure they have to be seperate. I'm using AngularJS, so these nested repeaters can get confusing. Here's my code:

```
 <div class="container" >
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead><tr>
                <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
            <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                <td>
              <!--insert a bunch of ng-repeats and other tds-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead><tr>
                <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
                <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
            <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                <td>
              <!--insert basically the same thing with less data-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using the bootstrap columns does bring the smaller one to the right (as expected), but I can't figure out a way to be able to make the height the same as the other one. I want the tables to line up perfectly, as if they were sort of the same table. Should I nest them? I'm not sure what to do, and was hoping someone had dealt with this before or could help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your best bet would be to nest them. With your current markup, there isn't a way for CSS to say "make these tables the same height". I would have said use `flexbox`, but since each table is in it's own column, there's no way (using CSS) for them to compare heights. You could use Javascript/jQuery to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it with jQuery, calculate height of both tables and one table's height adjust accordingly to 2nd table dynamically.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="one">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>One</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>Two</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>Three</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>Four</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="two">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>One</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>Two</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                    <td>Three</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = Math.max($("#one").height(), $("#two").height());
    $("#one").height(height);
    $("#two").height(height);
});
```

Note: `ids` assign to each table and bind with jQuery.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/72rv4kab/1/)

Comment: Is there an angular way to do this?

Comment: You'd use this same technique inside an Angular directive.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with angularjs and you should put `angularjs` tag in question so anyone knows about angular can post better answer.

Comment: @Shehary, please refine your code to account for if certain browsers have not yet rendered the height of either table.  That is, place it inside of a `setInterval()` that will scan the page, say, every 100 milliseconds.  If the two tables do not match the same height, then keep 'sniffing' the page - `else` set the `.height()` equal and `clearInterval()`.  I can add an answer if you do not understand what I'm driving at.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon, please be my guest, if you have better answer, post it, it's not just about answering the OP question, if you have better answer, post it, it may help the future readers down the road,.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can set variables that will hold the height of two tables in pixels.  Then you can add css directly that will alter the height of the target table to match the other table.

This approach gives you the flexibility to make the table a percentage height, whereby it does not have to be a fixed height and it can be scaled.  In such a case, you would just comment out the `//clearInterval(makeSameHeight)`

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/1cuaqou2/)

```js
//StackOverflow Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360755/how-to-stretch-a-table-to-another-tables-height
// Dynamically Adjust Table height
//09-02-2015

var makeSameHeight = setInterval(function() {
  var firstTable = $('table#one').height() + "px";
  var secondTable = $('table#two').height() + "px";
  if (firstTable === secondTable) {
    var doNothing = "";
    clearInterval(makeSameHeight);
  } else {
    $('table#two').css("height", firstTable);
  }
}, 100);
```

```css
table {
  border-collaspe: collapse;
  border: solid 1px black;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="one">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="two">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement. but you can try with the below code. you can have your loop inside the td tag.

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#999999" style="border:2px solid #333" valign="top">
        <div ng-repeat="obj in obj">
            <div ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2"> 
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#00CC33" style="border:2px solid #333" valign="top">
        <div ng-repeat="obj in obj">
            <div ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```